# imaplib "command SELECT illegal in state NONAUTH" error

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, imaplib

I'm attempting to create an application to retrieve and analyse emails sent through gmail. I'm using an alteration on the tutorial found here;
http://www.voidynullness.net/blog/2013/07/25/gmail-email-with-python-via-imap/

**readmail.py**

```
EMAIL_ACCOUNT = "*****"
PASSWD = "*****"
def process_mailbox(M):
    rv, data = M.search(None, "ALL")
    resp, items = M.search(None, "ALL")
    if rv != 'OK':
        print("No messages found!")
        return

    for num in data[0].split():
        rv, data, = M.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
        if rv != 'OK':
            print("ERROR getting message", num)
            return

        msg = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])
        hdr = email.header.make_header(email.header.decode_header(msg['Subject']))
        if msg.is_multipart():
            for part in msg.get_payload():
                body = part.get_payload()
        subject = str(hdr)
        print('Message %s: %s' % (num, subject))
        print('Body:', body)

M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com',993)


try:
    rv, data = M.login(EMAIL_ACCOUNT, PASSWD)
except imaplib.IMAP4.error:
    print ("LOGIN FAILED!!! ")
    sys.exit(1)

print(rv, data)

rv, data = M.select("INBOX")
if rv == 'OK':
    print("Processing mailbox...\n")
    process_mailbox(M)
    M.close()
else:
    print("ERROR: Unable to open mailbox ", rv)

M.logout()
```

When I run this code through the command line the output is as expected, however when ran through a basic flask import the entire thing falls apart.

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, request
from readmail import process_mailbox
import json
import imaplib
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def homepage():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/test')
def test():
    return json.dumps({'name': process_mailbox(imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com',993)).subject})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(use_reloader=True, debug=True)
```

The error I receive is;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1612, in 
full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\user\project\flask\venv\Project\app.py", line 13, in test
    return json.dumps({'name': 
process_mailbox(imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com',993)).subject})
  File "C:\Users\user\project\flask\venv\Project\readmail.py", line 14, in process_mailbox
    M.select('"[Gmail]/All Mail"')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\imaplib.py", line 683, in select
    typ, dat = self._simple_command(name, mailbox)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\imaplib.py", line 1134, in _simple_command
    return self._command_complete(name, self._command(name, *args))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\imaplib.py", line 882, in _command
    ', '.join(Commands[name])))imaplib.error: command SELECT illegal in state NONAUTH, only allowed in 
states AUTH, SELECTED
```

I've made several attempts this past week to find out ways to fix this error so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, looking at the end of the traceback, you've got `imaplib.error: command SELECT illegal in state NONAUTH, only allowed in states AUTH, SELECTED` - and going back to the two lines in the traceback for your code:

```
app.py, test ... return json.dumps({'name': process_mailbox(imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com',993)).subject})
readmail.py process_mailbox ... M.select('"[Gmail]/All Mail"')
```

I've trimmed some excess here, but in test, you are only connecting to the Gmail IMAP server, but not logging in. The following code is what your ffirst file does:

```
M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com',993)

try:
    rv, data = M.login(EMAIL_ACCOUNT, PASSWD)
except imaplib.IMAP4.error:
    print ("LOGIN FAILED!!! ")
    sys.exit(1)
```

Also, `process_mailbox` will only return null, it changes the object you've passed directly.